# Why my kali linux os is stops working AFTER 1-2 HOUR?

Tags: kali-linux, hang, lag

My Kali Linux OS is working fine but after a time period(like every 1-2 hour after) everything is suddenly stops nothing working only mouse courser moves but when i click on any icon it is also not working then I restart my system then it works fine but after some time period it stops again in every applications.
please help me.

system description:
RAM 4GB
INTERNAL HARD DISK HDD 1TB
GRAPHICS 2GB
PROCESSOR i5 10400
MOTHERBOARD ASUS PRIME H410M-E MOTHERBOARD

Comment: if it is related to a specific application, it might be a termperature issue. if mouse works but hangs/move/hangs/move and so on ... it is the way to investigate

Comment: CTRL-ALT-F1, log in as root and take it from there, if you can. Check with `journalctl` & the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Lastly, install another distro.

Comment: I agree that you might want to try another distro. Kali Linux is not for beginners, it’s a pen-testing distro with a specific role, and not really intended for new users to Linux.

Answer (score -4):

most likely you need to reinstall the bios betties and if this does not work then you need to take it to computer servicing place..GOOD LUCK.